# R plotting not working

Tags: r, plot

I'm using R on Windows 8, and I've created this little R script to plot

```
x = c(1,2,3)
y = c(3,4,5)
plot(x,y,pch=19,cex=2)
```

I'm then using CMD, going into \bin, and executing

```
Rscript.exe script.R
```

I'm getting this error

```
Error in (function (file = ifelse(onefile, "Rplots.pdf", "Rplot%03d.pdf"), : 
can't open file 'Rplots.pdf'
Calls : plot -> plot.default -> dev.hold -> <Anonymous>
Execution stopped
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Do you have the necessary permissions to write in the directory you are running the script in?